# Unable to configure Kgpg kwalletmanager

Tags: kde, encryption, gnupg, kwallet

Just installed Ubuntu 19.04 minimal with

```
apt install plasma-desktop sddm kwin --no-install-recommends
```

All good. Installed Brave Browser as described [here](https://support.brave.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018666072-How-do-I-install-Brave-on-Linux-using-the-terminal-).

Now opening brave, it opened "KDE wallet Service" dialog box, with default selection "Use GPG encryption...". Searching internet I used

```
sudo apt install kgpg kwalletmanager kwalletcli
```

Then I Opened kgpg and created key along with a wallet "firstKWallet" in `kwalletmanager`.

Now opening brave, it shows "kwalletd GPG backend - KDE Wallet Service" dialog box with message:

> Error when attempting to decrypt the wallet firstKWallet using GPG. If you're using a SmartCard, please ensure it's inserted then try again. Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device.

Following [this guide](https://d.sb/2016/11/gpg-inappropriate-ioctl-for-device-errors) edited `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` and created `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`. Then system restart.

Now opening brave, it shows "kwalletd GPG backend - KDE Wallet Service" dialog box with message:

> Error when attempting to decrypt the wallet firstKWallet using GPG. If you're using a SmartCard, please ensure it's inserted then try again. GPG error was No data.

What I am missing? How to make it work? Honestly, I've no idea what I'm doing (though, I know what GPG is).

In "kGpg-Key Management" Right clicking the key and selecting refresh key from keyserver gives

```
[GNUPG:] FAILURE refresh-keys
```

In KDE wallet manager, "The wallet is currently closed" is showing with a "Open..." button. upon clicking it goes back to "... GPG error was No data" dialog box

Comment: Have you seen this: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/wallet-gpg-error-at-start-up/14048

Comment: Thanks for the link, It didn't worked though.

Comment: Using `kleopatra` instead of `kgpg` solves the issue.

Comment: Okay. However, my question is based on `kgpg` not `kleopatra`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `kleopatra` instead of `kgpg` to solve issue.

Comment: How? What did you do?