# KdeWallet auto unlock at login

Tags: login, pam, kwallet

Just installed `ubuntu 19.04 minimal` with `apt install plasma-desktop sddm dolphin konsole kdeconnect --no-install-recommends` and `apt install kwin kleopatra kwalletmanager libpam-kwallet5`. All good. Installed Brave Browser as described [here](https://support.brave.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018666072-How-do-I-install-Brave-on-Linux-using-the-terminal-).

Currently I need to type two passwords, one at logging in, one to unlock wallet (almost immediately after login). Searching internet I found that it's possible to unlock both at a time from single password entry.

Tried installing folllowing packages:

`kwallet-pam`,`pam-kwallet5`: *Unable to locate package* `kwallet-pam`,`pam-kwallet5`

`pam-kwallet`: *Package pam-kwallet is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source. Package 'pam-kwallet' has no installation candidate*

Not solved. Any help? `pam-kwallet` referred to which package?

Comment: I have an actual Kubuntu 19.04 minimal install option with the [kubuntu-backports ppa](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports?field.series_filter=disco) to get updates to KDE Plasma, KDE Applications and KDE Frameworks shortly after they are listed [here](https://kde.org/announcements/). I haven't been bothered by the kwallet sign-in requirement. • *kleopatra* isn't installed. • Try `apt search kwallet` to see if any packages the output lists help you. • On which system did you install the software you mentioned?

Comment: Just noticed your [other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1157951/unable-to-configure-kgpg-kwalletmanager-help).

Comment: installed `signon-kwallet-extension`,`libpam-kwallet-common`,`libpam-kwallet4`,`libpam-kwallet5`,`libkf5wallet-bin`,`libkf5wallet-data`,`libkf5wallet-doc`,`libkf5wallet5`,`libkwalletbackend5-5`. Same issue.

Comment: Is this only with the Brave browser? What about Firefox, Google Chrome, Chromium?

Comment: I don't think browser has role in it. Because, when restarting, even without opening browser (I mean without doing anything) after login it asks for password to unlock wallet (some times with timeout error too, though clicking retry bring back to password entry box).

Comment: Hmm... I've never dealt with kwallet. In case you don't get help here, consider asking at [Kubuntu Forums](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/forumdisplay.php/242-KDE-neon), or [KDE Community Forums](https://forum.kde.org), or [reddit/kde](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/) or [reddit/kubuntu](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kubuntu/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues for `kwallet`. In a newly installed system, try this:
`apt install kleopatra kwalletmanager signon-kwallet-extension libpam-kwallet-common libpam-kwallet4 libpam-kwallet5 libkf5wallet-bin libkf5wallet-data libkf5wallet5 libkwalletbackend5-5 kwalletcli`

Do not create any wallet/certificate/key manually.

Install and open Brave browser. It will automatically create `kdewallet` and it should be able to unlock at login as per my test.

Comment: Will try and update accordingly.